# Can a male child be forced to convert?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah, minor-katan-child

I have read that an adoptive parent (for example) can convert a minor child as the change in status is considered to the advantage of the child so it does not need his consent. This child can [renounce](https://books.google.com/books?id=BnFaZE-Q1JMC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=halacha%20force%20conversion%20minor&source=bl&ots=ku4KiMwW-r&sig=ACfU3U0ch-mL7Z3LLa_27rgjhjlEUyXurA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ_LWVpq_pAhUtmXIEHajhAhEQ6AEwCnoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=halacha%20force%20conversion%20minor&f=false) the conversion when he reaches adulthood. But examples like this seem to revolve around converting a very small child without his consent. What about a boy of 12 who, though he may not be an adult in halachic eyes, would need to be coerced (and even knocked out) to accommodate a bris milah that he resists.

Can a parent/beit din physically force a child - who is making his contrary intentions clear via thrashing his body and yelling "no" - to undergo a bris milah for the sake of conversion?

Comment: Whether they can or not, it's a terrible idea to be sure.

Comment: No doubt (and it would lead to a question of "if you now the child will renounce, is it to his advantage to force it anyway", but one step at a time...)

Comment: I seem to recall those who say that the Rambam holds a non Jewish father owns his son to the point that he can convert him against his will. This seemingly would be until he's an adult, whenever that would be for a non jew

Comment: Where did you read that if I may ask?

Comment: [Mekor Baruch 2:40](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20818&st=&pgnum=104) understands from the Rambam that a non-Jew can convert their child to Judaism against their will. It sounds like from your question you're specifically asking about a Jewish person converting a child? The Jewish person has no relationship to this child so they can't do anything, only Beis Din.

Comment: I'm no expert on conversion - is the milah a requirement of the conversion? If the child only does mikveh but doesn't circumcise (and considering that when he reaches the age of 13 will anyway have to undergo a secondary process of accepting or denouncing the conversion), is he not Jewish?

Comment: @Harel where physically applicable, milah is definitely required and necessary